# Redirect output of one command to different files in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have a tab seperated string.

I want to copy 1 column to one file and the remaining columns to other file in one go..as that string can modify in between if I use 2 different commands.

I tried:

```
tab_seperated_string | awk -F"\t" '{ print $2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5} {print $1}'
```

2,3,4,5 should go to one file and 1 should go to another file.

Comment: I think I edited that and kept your intentions and command but please check and fix it if I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
tab_seperated_string | awk -F"\t" '{print $2,$3,$4,$5 > "file2"; print $1 > "file1"}' OFS="\t"
```

It will then save data to two different files.

By setting `OFS` to `\t`, you do not need all the `\t` in the print statement.

---

Here is another way if you have many fields that go to one file and first field to another:

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $1 > "file1"; sub(/[^\t]+\t/,""); print $0 > "file2"}' OFS="\t"
```

The `sub(/[^\t]+\t/,"")` removes first field and first tab.